# Row delete in trigger not call its delete trigger in MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I have created a delete trigger on table which deletes data from same table on some conditions. But in my case when trigger calls on delete a row, it delete one more row on some condition now I expected to call that trigger automatically once again but unfortunately trigger not calls again.

Please help me is there any particular reason for this kind of issue or trigger will not call recursively.

Thank You.

Comment: Though the question is vague it gives enough insight to the person who clearly examines and can easily come to a practical solution from the words "trigger not call recursively"

Comment: Won't that cause circular calculation?

Answer (score 1):

To enable recursion of Triggers you have to set it using the below code

```
ALTER DATABASE TestDB
   SET RECURSIVE_TRIGGERS ON;
```

Please check this link. It has all about recursion of Triggers

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx

Just search for the topic in the link.

Comment: If this is a correct answer please mark it as answer so that it will be helpful for the other users